# The method 'showDailyAtTime' isn't defined for the type 'FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-notifications, flutter-local-notification

error : The method `show Daily At Time` isn't defined for the type `Flutter Local Notifications Plugin`.

also another problem as ,

error : The method 'Time' isn't defined for the type '_New Entry Page State'.
whole problems specified code here
[image: Here the code error specified]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method has been removed from the version `15.0.0` you can check the change-log [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog#1500). This method was marked as deprecated in version `2.0.0` and new method was `zonedSchedule` were introduced for this functionality. you can check the details for that [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog#200)